# How do I convert a recursive object to a Collection in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

I have a recursive object, a linked list really:

```
public class LinkedList 
{
    public string UniqueKey { get; set; }
    public LinkedList LinkedList { get; set; }
}
```

LinkedList will have some object graph that will eventually end in LinkedList.LinkedList == null.

I would like to take all the objects in the graph and put them into a LinkedList collection so that I can iterate over them. How do I do this in C#? I feel as if there's a really easy way of going about this using yield or Linq voodoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  If you have control over the class you can make it `IEnumerable` directly.

```
public class LinkedListEnumerable : IEnumerable<string>
{
    LinkedList list;
    public LinkedListEnumerable(LinkedList l)
    {
        this.list = l;
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        LinkedList l = list;
        while(l != null)
        {
            yield return l.UniqueKey;
            l = l.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate over `LinkedListEnumerable` with a for-each loop.

Comment: Yeah, this is right. Except if you take the question verbatim then it should be `yield return l` instead of `yield return l.UniqueKey` right? All the same it should be easy enough for the OP to figure that part out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
public class LinkedList
{
    public string UniqueKey { get; set; }
    public LinkedList LinkedList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LinkedList> GetAllNodes()
    {
        if (LinkedList != null)
        {
            yield return LinkedList;
            foreach (var node in LinkedList.GetAllNodes())
                yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not very efficient. For a list with 100 items you will be creating 100 enumerators, and the last item has to pass through all of them before it's returned to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

There are no nice LINQ methods in the standard .NET library to allow some elegant LINQ voodoo, but you can use `Generate` method from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project and write this:

```
Enumerable
  .Generate(list, l => l.LinkedList)
  .TakeWhile(l => l != null).Select(l => l.UniqueKey);
```

It uses `Generate` to create "infinite" list of all elements - it is not actually infinite, because it is generated lazily and we stop using it as soon as we find `null` value at the end (using `TakeWhile`). Then we use `Select` to return a sequence of values (instead of linked list nodes).

This is essentially a nice declarative way of expressing the `while` loop solution posted by Matthew (and it should have roughly similar performance).

**EDIT** The `Generate` method looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> Generate(T current, Func<T, T> generator) {
  while(true) { 
    yield return current;
    current = generator(current);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, but unfortunately I cannot add any other libraries to the project. I'll be using this on future products though!

Comment: @Geoffrey: You can add the `Generate` method to your project (it is just 3 lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

I have a data structure in my project where an object can have a parent, and multiple children of itself.
To get all the parents I can use this function:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TModel> EnumerateParents<TModel>(TModel model, Func<TModel, TModel> parentSelector)
    {
        var curr = model;
        while ((curr = parentSelector.Invoke(curr)) != null)
        {
            yield return curr;
        }
    }
```

Usage looks like this: `_parents = ParentHelper.EnumerateParents(item, x => x.Parent).ToList();`

I also made a function to enumerate all children which can be done with this function:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TModel> EnumerateChildren<TModel>(TModel root, Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TModel>> childSelector)
    {
        var children = childSelector.Invoke(root);
        if (children == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            yield return child;

            foreach (var grandChild in EnumerateChildren(child, childSelector))
            {
                yield return grandChild;
            }
        }
    }
```

which can be used like this: `var children = ParentHelper.EnumerateChildren(item, x => x.Children)`

The last one is not asked in the question, but posted it anyways for if someone might need it.